Service name sent by otlp not visible in NewRelic traces
I am try to send tracing data to NewRelic via Opentelemetry collector. I run otel collector using docker-compose . I can see traces via trace.id but service.name is not visible. I tried using jaegar and service name is visible there
Below is the code snippet for Otlp
main.rs
fn main() -> {
    let tracer = opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
        .tracing()
        .with_exporter(
            opentelemetry_otlp::new_exporter()
            .tonic()
            .with_endpoint("http://localhost:4317")
         )
        .with_trace_config(
            trace::config()
                .with_sampler(Sampler::AlwaysOn)
                .with_id_generator(RandomIdGenerator::default())
                .with_resource(Resource::new(vec![KeyValue::new("service.name", "tracing-app")])),
        )
        .install_batch(opentelemetry_sdk::runtime::Tokio)
        .unwrap()
        .tracer("trace_demo");

    let otel_layer = Opentelemetry::new(tracer);
    let subscriber = Registry::default()
                       .with(otel_layer);
    subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber)
      .expect("Failed")
}

I am getting tracing data on otel collector and after tracking the trace.id on NewRelic, I was able to view trace id but service.name was not visible but while trying using the same code to export data to Jaegar , service name is present .
My log in otel-collector container looks like below:
Resource SchemaURL: 
Resource attributes:
     -> service.name: Str(tracing-app)
ScopeSpans #0
ScopeSpans SchemaURL: 
InstrumentationScope opentelemetry.instrumentation.jinja2 0.42b0
Span #0
    Trace ID       : ef80927d174b370869aabe7a8c2e75df
    Parent ID      : b58805531a48ee21
    ID             : 35e3b46ced0bc74e
    Name           : jinja2.compile
    Kind           : Internal
    Start time     : 2023-12-13 08:13:45.392929004 +0000 UTC
    End time       : 2023-12-13 08:13:45.401316639 +0000 UTC
    Status code    : Unset
    Status message : 
Attributes:
     -> jinja2.template_name: Str(blog/create.html)  

References : https://docs.rs/opentelemetry-otlp/latest/opentelemetry_otlp/
https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-opentelemetry-examples/tree/main/other-examples/collector/nr-config
Can anyone help
